# Reduce Chrome (Chromium) Memory Usage

Tags: linux, chromium

I have Chromium running on an embedded linux ARM system. What would be the best way to reduce its memory usage? I have tried running it with the "--single-process" switch, but that did not help much.

Are there any other command line switches or tips to get chromium to use less memory?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Pass this flags in Arguments to reduce the chromium memory usage

```
--disable-gpu
```

You can also refer this link: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/